Is it valid practice to intentionally omit association definition with Rails ActiveRecord?
While been working on Ruby on Rails application, I was suggested to omit ActiveRecord association intensionally by my coworker for it's defines unnecessary methods.
Example,
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to :person <- Omit belongs_to association, for this is not used in anywhere.
end

I'm confused by this advice, because it's suggested to define model associations completely on most resources which describes ActiveRecord association.
So, I'd like to ask the practice omitting association like this is valid or not.

"valid practice": Yes, you can easily determine that based on the fact that the application and models function successfully without the specification of the association. "best practice": Opinionated but I think in most cases the answer is no. If I can call person.pets then general assumption would be that I can also call pet.person and it would be surprising to find out that this method does not exist; however easily solved.

Thank you for comment. I think this is valid but not the best too. So, feels difficult to deal with this kind of advice.

According to the Bi-directional Associations from Rails Guide, if you specify relation in both models:

Active Record will attempt to automatically identify that these two models share a bi-directional association based on the association name. This information allows Active Record to:

Prevent needless queries for already-loaded data.
Prevent inconsistent data.
Autosave associations in more cases.
Validate the presence and absence of associations in more cases.


Therefore it is considered as best practice. Also you will be able to use methods and options provided by belongs_to.
However, it is not necessary to add them both, you can use one sided relation if it meets your needs.
